# OnModelCreating migration not working with 1/4 entity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have strange problem for which I can not get answer.. There are two quite similiar entities but with one migration works perfectly with another not.. The error is "**The expression 'c => c.User' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression**"

There are those two entities:

[image: Rating and Comment entities]

There is my onModelCreating method (problem is with the first and the forth):
[image: onModelCreating method]

Last two entities:

[image: User entity]

[image: Post entity]

It is looks like a simple problem, but I can not see where is problem and solve it by myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have missed {get; set;} for Comment's User and Post properties...